# Power Bi - Sort by column error

Tags: sorting, powerbi, desktop

I am currently trying to create some reports between the count of project by pipeline stage and I am having a problem where I cannot sort my chart with another column value which is integer values (1, 2, 3, 4), which is connected to each type of pipeline (not included in the chart). I previously did get the sorting with another column working using the 'Sort By Column' function on the modelling tab so I know it works but it isn't working for me anymore. When I press the 'Sort By Column' Button with the integer column, it does nothing to my charts. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Is there already visual-level sorting applied? That will over-ride Model-level sorting. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-report-change-sort

Comment: I am trying to sort by another column that is not in the visuals but in the same table. I know this works but doesn't work anymore...